# WPF: Cannot bind DataGrid to enum list

Tags: wpf, templates, data-binding, datagrid, enums

I'm having an unexpected problem binding to an enum list.  The binding silently fails and I am at a loss to explain why.

What this code should do is create a DataGrid, with the cell template as a combobox populated with the enum choices, and the selected item set to the list element.

This approach works fine elsewhere, for observable collections of objects which have an enum element as their .Value property.  It only seems to not like observable collections of enum element.

To be explicit, here are some example classes:

```
public enum EquipmentEnum { EquipmentA, EquipmentB, EquipmentC }

public class EquipmentClass { public EquipmentEnum Value { get; set; } }
```

This *works*:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding equipmentClassList}"> <!-- ObservableCollection<EquipmentClass> -->
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Equipment Used" >
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={local:Enumeration {x:Type EquipmentEnum}}}" 
                    SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=Value Converter={StaticResource convertEnumValueToIndex}, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                    DisplayMemberPath="Description" 
                    IsEditable="True" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This *does not* work:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding equipmentEnumList}"> <!-- ObservableCollection<EquipmentEnum> -->
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Equipment Used" >
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={local:Enumeration {x:Type EquipmentEnum}}}" 
                    SelectedIndex="{Binding Converter={StaticResource convertEnumValueToIndex}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    DisplayMemberPath="Description" 
                    IsEditable="True" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Just some notes:

1. `local:Enumeration` is a markup extension which simply provides the descriptions of the enum elements as a list.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably you haven't specified the convertback method in the convertEnumValueToIndex converter. And the property SelectedITem is better than the property SelectedIndex.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The converter does not seem to be the issue -- both directions are implemented, but are not called at all for this particular combobox. As I said, this exact structure works in other places, and I use the exact same instance of the converter class.

Comment: Anyway the problem is in SelectedIndex and its binding. It is bound to the full object which is single for all the columns of the datagrid. And what's wrong with the first xaml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The items of the bound collection are copied to the DataContext of the cells. You can use two-way bindings on properties of the object referenced by the DataContext, because you are effectively altering the same object referenced by the bound collection (i.e. {Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay} will work).

In your second example, you are trying to alter the object referenced by DataContext, but there is no facility in WPF to "update" the bound collection like that.

Basically, you can only alter the state of the object referenced by DataContext. You can't change what object is referenced by it, or by the bound collection.